# How to modify the transaction timeout value for a JBoss EAP 6.4 message driven bean using ActiveMQ resource adapter?

Tags: jboss, transactions, jboss7.x

My Setup:
JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21)
ActiveMQ 5.12,
ActiveMQ JCA Resource Adapter 5.12,
Message driven bean using ActiveMQ Queue

I need to increase the transaction timeout for a service, but I didn't found a working way to increase the transaction timeout value inherited from the default value from standalone.xml:

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
```

Changing this global value is not a preferred solution (it's a working workaround), I need to change it for one service only, especially the contained message driven bean!

Note: @TransactionTimeout annotation on the MDB or onMessage() method did not work as expected. The message initiated transactions are always killed by the Transaction Reaper:

```
11:41:47,959 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac112a2d:-6105c785:5718932a:af in state  RUN
11:41:47,960 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac112a2d:-6105c785:5718932a:af invoked while multiple threads active within it.
11:41:47,961 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffac112a2d:-6105c785:5718932a:af aborting with 1 threads active!
11:41:47,973 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffffac112a2d:-6105c785:5718932a:af
```

Anyone solved this before? I'm also thankful for useful hints.

Answer (score 1):

After a comprehensive research I'm quite sure, that there is really no solution to explicitly configure the Message Driven Bean transaction timeout in this setup.

The reason is, that the transaction is started by the messaging system and the responsible ActiveMQ JCA Resource Adapter does not support this feature.

Otherwise (e.g. when using HornetQ, which supports it), there are two ways to configure it:

- inside @MessageDriven annotation:
  `@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transactionTimeout", propertyValue = "..")`
- inside the deployment descriptor:
  `<message-driven-deployment ... >
      <config-property>
          <config-property-name>transactionTimeout</config-property-name>
          <config-property-value>...</config-property-value>
      </config-property>
  </message-driven-deployment>`

Comment: The transaction timeout for the session in milliseconds. This is not a mandatory value. A good reference can be seen here: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout